# How to modify header in r using gtsummary package?

Tags: r, gtsummary

Hopefully, a simple answer that someone knows off the top of their head!

I am using `tbl_summary` and trying to modify my header to have n(%) instead of the standard format of N = 57. I would normally use `modify_header(stat_by)` but can't when `by` isn't included.

Example:

```
trial %>%
  select(trt, marker, stage) %>%
  tbl_summary() %>%
  modify_header(stat_by = "**{level}**, n(%)")
```

Any ideas most appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit the text of your header, you can use the `update` argument in `modify_header()`. `stat_0` refers to the statistic column, so this is the one you need to change:

```
library(gtsummary)

trial %>%
  select(trt, marker, stage) %>%
  tbl_summary() %>%
  modify_header(update = stat_0 ~ "**n(%)**")
```

You can use {glue} syntax if you want to insert a statistic as well:

```
trial %>%
  select(trt, marker, stage) %>%
  tbl_summary() %>%
  modify_header(update = stat_0 ~ "**n(%), N = {N}**")
```

Good luck!

Comment: Nice! You can use the function `show_header_names()` to print the column names and their current headers. 

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. Thanks kittykatstat and Daniel! I have another issue. I just updated to using all_stat_cols(TRUE) and get an error with I try to include {level} or {n}. It works if stat_0 isn't included, so I tried with with all_stat_cols(FALSE) and a separate stat_0 ~ "Total n = {n}", but still get the error "Error: glue cannot interpolate functions into strings. * object 'n' is a function."  Any help appreciated!